# N-dimensional Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fourier-transform

I ran into this Fourier transform: $\int_{ \mathbb{R} ^n}e^{-\pi \sum_{k=1}^{n}u_i \mid c^k_1 x_1+c_2^k x_2...+c^k_n x_n \mid^2}e^{-2\pi i(m_1x_1+m_2x_2...+m_n x_n))}dx_1dx_2...dx_n$ ($c^k_a$ is the ath constant in a set k, not $(c_a)^k$, and $u_i$ is a constant) I thought about substituting the equation in the absolute value sign with another variable so that I could separate the sum in the exponent, but I don't know how to deal with the differential under that substitution. I believe there is a way to solve this, but I don't know how. If someone could show me I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: $\exp(-\pi t^2)$ is its own Fourier transform. $h(x) = \exp(-\pi\sum_k |x_k|^2)$ is its own Fourier transform. Thus the Fourier transform of $h(M x)$ is $|\det(M)|^{-1} h(M^{-\top} x)$ (proof : from the volume definition of $\det$,  $d^n(Mx) = \det(M)d^nx$). In the Dedekind zeta function setting all the point is to understand that lattice generated by $M^{-\top}$ (obviously try with imaginary and real quadratic number fields)

Comment: @reuns so the M would be the same matrix used to calculate the determinant times the norm of the ideal?